# Unable to get tensorflow to recognize my GPU on Windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, dll, gpu, conda

I had previously installed the tensorflow-gpu 2.5.0 package using conda on my machine in 2 envrionments.  In a python 3.7 environment, everything worked well.  In a python 3.8 environment, I was having issues, but I found that if I loaded certain libraries first, I was able to get tensorflow to recognize my GPU.

Unfortunately, I ended up with some issues in those environments, and I had to remove them.

Now, no matter how I try, I cannot get tensorflow to load cudart64_110.dll and, therefore, recognize my GPU.  I have tried installing using the tensorflow-gpu 2.5.0 package using conda, and I have tried following the instructions on the official tensorflow.org page, but in neither case will tensorflow load the cudart64_110.dll library.

However, I also have spacy installed in my environment, and if I import spacy, I get the following messages:

```
2022-09-16 13:42:58.588234: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-09-16 13:42:58.588417: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-09-16 13:43:00.551253: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2022-09-16 13:43:00.555761: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.425GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2022-09-16 13:43:00.556393: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-09-16 13:43:00.556491: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2022-09-16 13:43:00.556787: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2022-09-16 13:43:00.557350: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2022-09-16 13:43:00.557720: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2022-09-16 13:43:00.558789: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2022-09-16 13:43:00.559043: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2022-09-16 13:43:00.559383: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2022-09-16 13:43:00.559746: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1766] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

So, clearly, some of the CUDA libraries are being opened correctly, but not all.

I've tried uninstalling miniconda & reinstalling it, but I get the same issues.

I'm at a loss as to why tensorflow continues to give me these problems.

Comment: You need to properly install the exact CUDA version that your tensorflow was built with/is expecting.  It [seems to be expecting](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-2-5-with-gpu-device-python-3-9-cuda-11-2-2-cudnn-8-1-1-conda-environment-windows-10/1385) CUDA 11.2.2 and cuDNN 8.1.1.

Comment: I've tried both using the tensorflow-gpu conda package (which may actually have been built using cudatoolkit 11.3 and cudnn 8.2) and separately, installing exactly as per the tensorflow documentation page: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native, but in neither case will it load cudart64_110.dll.

Comment: You also need to have those installations (binary) paths in *%PATH%*.

Comment: I know they are in my PATH because `where cudart64_110.dll` finds them in the correct location.

I have also found that after adding some additional packages to my environment with the tensorflow-gpu package, I'm able to get tensorflow to load all of the CUDA libraries, but only by loading spacy first!  I'm trying to figure out exactly which package seems to enable this behavior, although I have no idea why this would cause the libraries to be loaded correctly.

Comment: Please try again by installing GPU setup in both the virtual environments using `conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0`. Let us know if the issue still persists.